# Customerror page in asp.net webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, custom-error-pages

I am developping an Asp.NET web application with visual studio 2015 and running it under IIS Express. I want to add a custom error page to it.

First, in the web.config file, I added customErrors markup under the system.web section. But it didn't seem to have any effect.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error.aspx">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

So I added an httpErrors markup under system.webServer. And it showed me a blank page.

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

So I changed the above httpErrors markup by this one :

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" defaultPath="/Error.aspx">
  <clear/>
  <error path="/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" statusCode="404"/>
</httpErrors>
```

And it showed me the "lock violation" error. I Tried to remove ,defaultPath in the applicationHost.config file, rebooted the computer, but the same error appears

Even in Global.asax, the Application_Error is not fired in the case of some error like 404.

Does someone have any clue ?

**Edit** :
I tried to do the same thing in a new solution :
So I created a new web application - Blank webforms template. Same result.
But when I created a new web application - Blank MVC solution, it worked.

Is there any difference in the config between webforms and mvc? Is someone else have the same issue whith the webforms template ?

Comment: How is your config in App pool and site at IIS ?

Comment: I am using IIS Express. So I'm not doing any server configuration

Answer (score 0):

I was able to redirect to error page. I tried this in my current MVC project. Below is excerpt of what i did

1. Used existing error page in my solution under Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
2. Used your custom errors parameters

`<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml" />
  </customErrors>`

3. Threw 404 purposefully in my Index.cshtml

`@Response.StatusCode=404
 @Response.End()`

Hint: Please try to see the path and how you are testing 404 error

Comment: I have my error page named Error.aspx under the root of the server so i set defaultRedirect="/Error.aspx" (also tried defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx") and to test the 404 i just write in the address bar a URL pointing to a non existing page